# Use char type for flag?

Tags: c

I would like to write my code using the type char for flags as it is the same or smaller than an int;
Is there a cleaner way to do this than:

```
typedef char flag;
#define FLAG1FORSWITCH1 'a'
#define FLAG2FORSWITCH1 'b'
#define FLAG1FORSWITCH2 'a'
```

where case is a portion of code that uses flags.

Edit an example would be:

```
flag f
f = getffromrelevantplace();
switch(f){
         case: FLAG1FORSWITCH1
                 <code>
                 break
        case: FLAG2FORSWITCH1
                 <code>
                 break
}
```

Comment: Is space really more important than performance in your application?

Comment: Can you add more clarity to this question?

Comment: It might help to show an example of your intended use of the "flags"

Comment: Just use an enum - it will give you better code readability and type safety. Unless you are doing embedded development or dealing with massive datasets, or can prove through profiling that this is causing a performance issue, don't bother micro-optimising.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what would be the performance drop? Is it bc int is a more natural data type on most hardware?

Comment: Could you clarify what is not "clean" about this approach? Specifying flags via `#define` constants is a common practice. POSIX is full of them!

Comment: Using `enum` rather than `#define` reduces risk of a name clash.  Also this would not normally be called "flags" -- that refers to binary bits that can be combined

Comment: What you have illustrated with your example can be called `messages` rather than `flags`. Usually, flags are multiple values present in the same variable that tell **how** the code should be executed. Messages are just numbers that will tell **what part of the code** should be executed or how to handle some data.

Comment: @Tudor thanks that makes sense basically I am just wanting to use one byte variables to store said messages as 2^8 is well and truly enough different messages for me and am wondering why enum defaults to int (also could just cast enum variables to type char like one does with fgetc?)

Comment: Because i like macros more than enums (just personal prefference, a windows.h guy) i have no experience with them. I cannot tell anything about enums. Also, you can get quite clean code if you name the macros with exactly what they mean.

Comment: @Tudor Thanks, I think I'll stick with your suggestion then :)

Comment: @CMac Yes, that's right. Generally, `int` will be whatever data type is fastest on the platform. There are a few exceptions, but they're quite rare these days.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sweet thanks - this is the perfect response I'll reflect on how to word my questions better. I wondered why ansi had int as the enum standard, as there would be a way to char enums if there wasn't a reason.

Comment: Most compilers have extensions or options to size an `enum` type to the smallest one. For GCC you can add `__attribute__((packed))` to the `enum`. I think the standard chose `int` as base type because of integer promotion. Why always (implicitly) cast an `enum` with some necessary machine code, if it could be an `int` based type up-front? -- @Tudor Yes, WIndows guys tend to ignore type safety. ;-) Coming from an safety-related embedded background, the Windows programming world is lawless, chaotic and full of dangerous constructions. And the results show.

Comment: @thebusybee Totally agree on the last part :)